# Curved background image using clip path

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my background image bottom border to be curved like the image below. How do I make it using clip-path?
[here is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTNG9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, maybe it would help someone in future

```
clip-path: ellipse(100% 55% at 48% 44%);
```